# iterator in list container

Tags: c++, stl

I read somewhere that list container is implemented as doubly linked list so if that is true then how can we iterate through list container by using `++` operator https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-iterators-c/ here it is given that iterator of list container is bidirectional which seems to be understandable but bidirectional iterator can iterate by using `++` or `--` which should not be possible as if we could do that then list would have contiguous memory allocation which would make it similar to vector.

I also tried by doing in code and it turns out that it is valid to do `++` on `list<int>::iterator`.

So, please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: `++` is just a token that programmers use to mean "go to the next thing". This can be implemented whether it's storing the memory contiguously or not.

Comment: `++` is a function.  The iterator you provide implements that function.  Thus it can do whatever you want it to do.  For `std::list::iterator`, it goes to the next node.

Comment: So is ++ operator overloaded for std::list objects?

Comment: It is implemented in the iterator.

Comment: The point is that you do `++` on the iterator, not on the list or the objects in the list. This way the implementation of the iterator can make sure that `++` moves you to the next element, no matter what kind of container is being used, or what the container stores.

Comment: so in list::iterator there is operator++ function which makes this=this->next right?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 4):

> So, please tell me where I am wrong.

You seem to wrong in your assumption that the operator ++ has something to do with contiguous memory.

++ is simply an operator that does different things to objects of different types. Conventionally, it does incrementation. On an integer, it increases the value by 1. On an iterator, it makes the iterator refer to the next sibling element. The pre-increment operator is supported by all iterators. and post-increment is supported by all input iterators and output iterators.

Pointer is an example of an iterator type. It is an iterator for arrays. Just like all other iterator types, it too supports operator ++.

Iterators for all other types than arrays are not pointers. Given that pointers are the only fundamental types that are iterators, this means that all other iterator types are classes. Classes do not have operator ++ by default, but the operator can be overloaded for classes. Iterators must have such overload.

> so in `list::iterator` there is `operator++` function which makes `this=this->next` right?

Not quite. `this` cannot be modified. It would be something like `this->node = this->node->next`.

Comment: The confusion probably arises from the fact that a pointer is an iterator (not all iterators are pointers)

Comment: no actually just as he said i forgot that iterator is a class and ++ operator could have been overloaded

Answer (score 1):

The `operator++` implementation of an iterator is dependent on the container. For a list, the iterator must keep track somehow of the next and prev node and return that when you do `++` or `--`.